# Is wearing a taweez haram?

Tags: halal-haram, tawiz

Some people say that Tawees are Haram. But I have also heard the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) gave a Hasan and Husain Taweez to protect them.

Taweez is a piece of paper with Quranic verses and Duas people keep them for protection. Sometimes people recite verses of the Quran and then blow around themselves and others for protection.

Comment: This looks like a Truth question; a basic search on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%27wiz) shows that this is a matter in which there is a clear difference of opinion, and as-written you will only attract arguments for or against the practice rather than useful *answers*. Please see relevant meta discussion http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1442/22 to better understand why these sorts of questions do not work well under the Stack Exchange model.

Comment: @Aisha, Its not for taweez, as the people who came to prophet were kafir and wearing amulate made according to there faith. taweez is different I haven't found any hadith witch says not to wear taweez made with Quranic verses, its permissible in hanafi fiqh to wear taweez  and its ijma of ahle ilm & fiqh..http://www.alahazrat.net/islam/taweez.php

Comment: @Ali786 That is not true. The consensus among the majority of the ulema is tying a thread on one's body believing it to protect from evil is shirk. If writing some duas and placing it the thread would have protected people, the people would rather have whole Quran in a miniature format put in the taawiz to gain max protection. No such protection exists.  I have even seen people putting taawiz on their left legs after reciting ayahs on them which is so wrong.The threads are man made and neither harm nor protect. The Sunnah is to recite and blow the duas or ayahs on the persons directly.

Comment: @Ahmed, Please provide references this seems all your opinions, and I am talking about wearing taweez not about threads and the people who are wearing on thier left leg is wrong not wearing taweez is haram.

Answer (score 8):

Bismillah

## Ta`weez

Ta`weez in all forms (ones you hang around neck, around wrist etc) is haraam and form of shirk. I wouldn't have said such a big statement had i not researched on it in much greater detail.

> 'Uqbah ibn 'Aamir al-Juhanee (radiyaAllaahu ‘anhu) narrated that some people came to the Messenger of Allaah (SAW) and he took Bai’ah (Pledge of Allegiance) from nine and left one. So they said: “Oh Messenger of Allaah, you took Bai’ah from nine and you left this one.” He said: ((Verily upon him is an amulet [tameemah])). So his hand reached out to cut it, then he took Bai'ah from him and said: **Whoever wears an amulet then verily he has committed shirk**. Reported by Ahmed: 4/156 with an authentic chain, and al-Haakim: 4/219 and it has been authenticated by ash-Shaykh al-Albaanee (rahimahullaah) in as-Saheehah, no. 492 and made Hasan by ash-Shaykh Muqbil in al-Jaami’ as-Saheeh: 6/294
>
> "Ruwayfa' ibn Thaabit (radiyAllaahu ‘anhu) narrated that the Messenger of Allah (SAW) said: Oh Ruwayfa', perhaps you will live long after me so inform the people that **whoever ties a knot in his beard or wears a string necklace or cleans his private parts with the excrement of animals bones, then verily Muhammad is free from him**" - Reported by an-Nisaa’ee in az-Zeenah, chapter (12)
>   8/135-136, no. 5067 with an authentic chain, and Ahmed: 4/108 and 109, and Abu Daawud, no. 36, and authenticated by our Shaykh al-Albaanee in al-Mishkaat, no. 351 and Saheeh al-Jaami’, no. 7910
>
> "‘Abbaad ibn Tameem narrated from Abaa Basheer al-Ansaaree (radiyAllaahu ‘anhu) who informed him that he was in the company of the Messenger of Allah of his journeys. He (Abu Basheer) said: The Messenger of Allah (SAW) sent a messenger ordering: **There shall not remain any necklace of string or any other kind of necklace round the necks of camels except it is cut off**" - Reported by
>   [Al-Bukhari in book of Jihaad, no. 3005](http://muflihun.com/bukhari/52/249) and [Abu Dawud](http://muflihun.com/abudawud/14/2546).
>
> "Narrated ‘Abdullaah ibn Mas’ood (radiyAllaahu ‘anhu) who said that the Messenger of Allah said: **Verily incantations [ar-Ruqaa], amulets [at-Tamaa'im] and bewitchment** [at-Tiwalah 1 ] are shirk" - Narrated by Aboo Daawud, no. 3883 and made Hasan by ash-Shaykh Muqbil in al-Jaami’ as-Saheeh: 4/499, and al-Haakim: 4/217 and authenticated by ash-Shaykh al-Albaanee

## Reciting Al-Mu’awwidhatan

There are many benefits of reciting ‘Al-Mu’awwidhatan’ i.e, Qur'an 113 (Al-falaq) and Qur'an 114 (An-naas). If you see reason of revelation of these two chapters of Qur'an you will find out they are revealed for this purpose, hence very useful.

> "'A'isha reported that when any of the members of the household fell ill Allah's Messenger (may
>   peace be upon him) used to blow over him by reciting Mu'awwidhatan, and when he suffered from
>   illness of which he died I used to blow over him and rubbed his body with his hand for his hand
>   had greater healing power than my hand." - [Sahih Muslim Book 26 Number 5439](http://muflihun.com/muslim/26/5439)
>
> "'A'isha reported that when Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) fell ill, he recited over his
>   body Mu'awwidhatan and blew over him and when his sickness was aggravated I used to recite
>   over him and rub him with his band with the hope that it was more blessed." - [Sahih Muslim Book
>   26 Number 5440](http://muflihun.com/muslim/26/5440)

Allah knows best

Comment: "Amr ibn Shu'aib (may Allah be pleased with him) said that 'Rasulu'llah(may Allah bless him and grant him peace) taught my father and grandfather a du'a which we would read before going to sleep, to protect us from fear and anguish.We told our elder children to recite this du'a before going to sleep as well.But for those children who were not yet literate, we would write it and then put it around their necks" ?????

Comment: @Aisha, Read carefully sister - "we would write it and then put it around their necks" - it's not what Rusul-Allah (SAW) asked them to do. I am not sure what He (SAW) would have said, had he seen him doing so but I know for the fact from hadiths that I mentioned that it's clearly forbidden. Also see [Dr. Zakir Naik's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzBDo7cGQKE) if you understand urdu / hindi (not sure what you are originally from so adding condition) - On top of that, why don't you memorize dua'? This hadith is talking about iliterate children.
Allah knows best

Comment: I find no such hadith that brother has mentioned in Abu Dawud Book of medicine (I have darussalam copy). I don't know where did he pick up from. There are two ahaadith I found in Abu Dawud talking about tawidth
Chapter 17. Wearing Amulets (Tama 'im) : 3883 (Da'if) and 3884(Sahih), - Please read

Comment: I have seen it in several Islam Question and answer site where a scholar answers the questions and they have mention the hadith about taweez being put on children's arms for protection as well as the hadiths that you have mentioned. Also none of the hadiths say taweez with du'a or quranic verses are haram that is why scholars argue between themseleves as some of them believe all amulets are haram where as some believe ones with Quranic verses or du'a are not haram because you are still relying on Allah and his words to protect you or heal you.

Comment: I have seen Zakir Naiks video but he says that there is no verse in the Qur'an and there are no hadiths talking about Taweez.

Comment: @Aisha : When you buy tablets from the pharmacy, would you be cured by eating them or by hanging it around the neck? Similarly the Quran is considered to be a 'Shifa' (cure) and there's no point in hanging it around the neck, it is to be read, understood and practiced upon...

Comment: @Aisha If you have seen Dr. Zakir Naik's video claiming that there is no hadith talking about taweez what about ahaadith in this answer? Surely there are many ahaadith as stated above and ref given above (you may check) but do listen to http://bit.ly/1K4hf80

Comment: https://muflihun.com/blog/taweez

Comment: Its not for taweez, as the people who came to prophet were kafir and wearing amulate made according to there faith. taweez is diffrent your research isn't complete its permissible in hanafi fiqh to wear taweez  and its ijma of ulma..

Answer (score 2):

My sincere advice to you. If you encounter something in your life, a practice, a custom, a belief, a tradition etc. just ask yourself or seek if it was there back then at the time of the Prophet (pbuh) or not. Did he used to it or not. Or seek if Qur'an talks about it or not.

Rest, which are not dated back to the exact time of Prophet (pbuh) are all made up things later. The people who follow those traditions simply at max they can do is justify their behavior with that which is there in Islam. Why invent things in the first place? then rotate it and try to prove it right according to Islam. Why? At the first place, what is the need to invent things when the basic things which are out there sufficient and **more than enough**. Because **Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) was a complete way to the truth and the life.** Although, those added things maybe right, but why are they needed at all? When the basic things suffice our need.

If you want to stay protected by the creator just remember him, and ask him to protect you. Simple. I can say, it need not be even in Arabic. Believing that God will prioritize you with a Tawiz in Arabic letters of verses in contrast to the one who simply called on God, is... I don't think is a good idea.

So, instead of Questioning why is tawiz Haram, just question, is it damn necessary? Will God protect me only if I wear a Tawiz? Will I be preferred more by God if I wear a tawiz or will I be preferred more if I remember God by saying hundred times "Subhan Allah".

### Is it Haram?

Irrespective of whether there are Qur'anic Ayahs in that amulet or not, when Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) said it, he meant it. (I don't have anything extra other than those Hadith which "[mkhan3189](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/4374/mkhan3189)" provided in his [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12710/11938))

### Why is it Haram?

To this contemporary issue I don't think Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) has explained the reason as why is it Haram. But to **guess**, it is Haram because there might come a time, suppose when you're protected from something bad, and you believe were protected by 'something', and that 'something' are the pieces of mere papers in your neck written in some Arabic letters which one could hardly read without a microscope. Then and right then, you might not even come close to thinking that it is God who protected you.

And if you believe that you were saved, because of those pieces of paper with some Arabic font, then according to classic Islamic definition it is termed as <strike>Haram</strike> '*Shirk'*. because the 'Tawiz' protected you, or in other words you believe some material object protected you.

A piece of advice, as the famous and well educated Christian scholars say, "*If you know something would lead to sin, then don't play with it or don't taste it at the first place in order to explore how would it feel like, because your fear might come true, because sins are addictive".*

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: Its not for taweez, as the people who came to prophet were kafir and wearing amulate made according to there faith. taweez is diffrent..