# Are taweez (amulets) haram?

Tags: halal-haram, tawiz

Are [taweez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%27wiz) (amulets) haram? Kindly provide references from Quran and/or Hadith.

Some Ulama say it is ja'iz (not haram) and now I am confused and would like to know the real ruling. Please back your answers with references from Quran or Authentic Ahadeeth.

Comment: I had answered this in detail previously. https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12679/are-taweez-haram/12710. May Allah reward you with goodness and guide us all to the truth and give us ability to follow the truth and abstain from falsehood.

Answer (score 1):

In the name of Allah, the most gracious, the ever merciful, peace and blessings be upon the messenger of Allah.
Salam Sister,
Taweez are not haram in general, at the time of the prophet(peace and blessings be upon him) people used to wear taweez, however, taweez is also used for doing black magic, these taweez have hidden shapes and things so that black magic takes places in a particular house or a place, you can see many youtube videos on these, the only haram taweez are the taweez based on shirk and kufr, which includes these taweez made for the purpose of black magic, a taweez should be checked properly,other than that, taweez are halal, but they should not be worn so that one could be succesful or something like that, it is Allah who will give blessings, not the taweez, it is just a way with which Allah gives blessins, for example, when we take medicine it not the medicine which cures us, it is rather Allah curing us, it is just a way by which he is curing us, just like that, taweez is also just a way. Here is the video I would use as a reference, it is in Urdu https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGYoHSxQge0

Comment: @HamzaIslam **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification; they are *not* intended for argument and debate or for proving who is or is not "more correct".

Answer (score 0):

Scholars of Sunni islam have little difference of opinion on this issue. Some Salaf scholars said they are allowed as long as they only have Quran, but to be on safe side,and Stronger opinion is that its better to avoid all forms of Tazeez, as there Can be danger in using it, as person can commit shirk, like this hadith

> It was narrated that ‘Uqbah ibn ‘Aamir said: I heard the Messenger of
>   Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say: “Whoever wears
>   an amulet, may Allaah not fulfil his need, and whoever wears a
>   sea-shell, may Allaah not give him peace.”
>
> (Narrated by Ahmad, 16951)

for more detailed answer from Consensus of Scholars, please consult this Fatwa
https://islamqa.info/en/10543